# Can i transform stm32f4** 's function(Flash_Erase) to stm32f1** function?

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, stm32cubeide, stm32f1

I have a little project and I need to store wifi config in stm32 but I don't want to use EEPROM so I decided to use STM32F103C8's flash memory.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qt3T7ij9qYY in this video this guy uses STM32F4** series.  At blue arrow it shows `flash_erase_sector`.  This function is defined in `stm32f4**_hal_flash_ex.h`. S I wonder can I integrate this function to stm32f103c8?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `FLASH_Erase_Sector()` does not exist in STM32CubeF1. There is a similar function called `HAL_FLASHEx_Erase()`. It might fit your purpose.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at [AN2594
application note: EEPROM emulation
in STM32F10x microcontrollers](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an2594-eeprom-emulation-in-stm32f10x-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf)